# Is it possible to return the method from a stub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I'm not sure it's the best title but it's hard to explain so I'll put some code.

```
class Bar
  include Errors

  def self.foo
    raise_error("something")
    puts "should not go here"
  end
end
```

And I've this spec:

```
it ""
  stub(Bar.new).raise_error { return }
end
```

I want some how to return the method on foo scope, this give me "unexpected return"

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Basically I'm testing some private method on controller which using this raise_error that raises error and I also have rescue_from that renders the exception on my way. 
On this I don't want to test controller flow, so I'm doing it by using send method on controller.

Answer (score 0):

would you like to `unstub` some method?

Yes it is possible https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class#any-instance-unstub

```
MyModel.any_instance.stub(:my_method)
MyModel.any_instance.unstub(:my_method)
```